# Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in QuickAccordion

Tags: 7

```
Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in QuickAccordion->add_attached() (line 100 of /sites/all/modules/quicktabs/plugins/QuickAccordion.inc).
```

After spending a while Googling I found some stuff related to AJAX and Views for this error in relation to quicktabs, but I cannot find anything on what's throwing this error on my site.

I don't know what's causing it nor do I know how to fix it.

I thought it may have something to do with the jquery version I'm using, but switching to various different versions didn't resolve it

I thought it might be due to a view on the same page, but not included in teh same view using AJAX, but disabling AJAX on the view did not resolve it.

I thought it may be due to the version of quicktabs I was using, but upgrading to the latest dev version did not solve the issue.

All other modules and Drupal core are all up to date on the latest version. This is the only dev module we're using.

Have you seen this before? Can you help me with this error?

Line 100 is:

```
if (!isset($qtkey) || !array_key_exists('qt_' . $name, $javascript['settings']['data'][$qtkey]['quicktabs'])) {
      $quicktabs_array = array('name' => $name, 'active_tab' => $this->quickset->getActiveTab(), 'options' => $options['jquery_ui'], 'history' => $options['history']);
      $attached['js'][] = array('data' => array('quicktabs' => array('qt_'. $name => $quicktabs_array)), 'type' => 'setting');
    }
    return $attached;
  }
```

Comment: which version of [quicktabs Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) you use, because because i have install actual version `7.x-3.8`, the `line 100` of `plugins/QuickAccordion.inc` there is only `}` ? can you please post the used version?

Comment: I'm using the latest dev release - 7.x-3.x-dev. I *was* using 7.x-3.8, but had the same problem. I updated to the dev version in hopes it would resolve my issue, but alas, it did not.

Line 100 from the QuickAccordion.inc has been added to above.

Comment: Okay, can you try to apply my patch i have added to [the  issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs/issues/3002569), still need test by the community. Good luck.